# Avoiding Errors When Attempting to Load an Unavailable File

Tags: php, load, domdocument

Using php I want to load XML files from several websites and want to prevent errors if my one of the sites is down. I'm using this code to access the URL.

```
function get_xml($url){
 $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc->load($url); // This is the line causing errors
 $channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
 ...
```

If there is no xml feed available at $url I get lots of error messages like:

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Space required after the Public Identifier

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): SystemLiteral " or ' expected

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 5 and head

What can I do to prevent $url from attempting to load if the feed isn't available?
I've tried:

```
if(file_exists($url)){
$xmlDoc->load('$url');
}
```

And things with fopen and @load but I could well have been using them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
if (!@$xmlDoc->load($url)){
  return FALSE;
}
```

Your function `get_xml` will return immediately `FALSE` if the method `load` fails to load the XML data

Comment: Brilliant! I just replaced $xmlDoc->load($url); with your code and it solved hours of headaches in seconds!. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

In theory *(and if I remember correctly)*, you should be able to catch those errors *(so you call deal with them yourself, instead of having them displayed)* using the **[libxml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php)<sup>1</sup> functions**.

I'm especially thinking about [**`libxml_use_internal_errors()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) :

> `libxml_use_internal_errors()` allows you to disable standard libxml
>   errors and enable user error handling.

<sup>1.</sup><sub>`libxml` being the library that's using internally by `DOMDocument` -- and `SimpleXML`, btw</sub>